# NodeJS fetch is returning more data than it should, and it's not the data my Flask server is sending it

Tags: python, node.js, react-native, flask, fetch-api

**I am running a NodeJS fetch() in my React Native app to get data from my Flask Heroku server**

This is what the Flask server does:

*(I'm sure it returns this normally because when I go to the URL in my browser, it is a blank page with the word "false")*

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    
    #some code that I'm sure is working and doesn't need to be shown
    
    return jsonify(False)
```

This is the code that the React Native app does:

```
console.log(address)

var returned = await fetch(address)

console.log(JSON.stringify(returned))
```

*I know the address that it is using, since I'm printing it to the console. I have gone to this exact URL, copy-pasted from my console, in the browser and the data returned looks fine*

Here is what the React Native fetch() returns:

```
{"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"headers":{"map":{"content-length":"6","connection":"keep-alive","content-type":"application/json","date":"Wed, 26 Aug 2020 17:46:31 GMT","via":"1.1 vegur","server":"gunicorn/20.0.4","cache-control":"public, max-age=0"}},"url":"[MY_URL_IS_HERE]/login?username=W&tag=L","bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":6,"offset":0,"blobId":"e450e243-9a7e-4a35-8e47-f8e9f3c7a58c","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":6,"offset":0,"blobId":"e450e243-9a7e-4a35-8e47-f8e9f3c7a58c","__collector":{}}}}
```

I've looked at many guides and StackOverflow posts online, but none of them have helped me parse/get better data than this.

**How do I get my data?**

Comment: They're just headers aren't they?

Comment: I think so, but I don't know where to find my data in these headers, or if it's even there. Most tutorials have made it seem as simple as a "JSON.stringify(returned)", "returned.blob()", or something similar, though none of them have seemed to work for me.

Comment: Ok, well I don't understand the downvote, but you can paste into jsonlint.com and see the response. Some of that response does seem unnecessary but I don't think I'm seeing the full picture

Comment: Yeah, look at what Ayush posted, you are logging the fetch request, not the data, you need to pull out just the data from the fetch request. I would recommend you look at the fetch api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @WarrenJennings this is basically what fetch returns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response so to read the response body you need to use the functions `.json`, `.text` etc, as mentioned in this link

Comment: I added a .json() to the result, and now it returns a promise with some data that doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't my "await" mean that it will wait till the promise is fulfilled to return the data? This is what it returns: `Promise { "_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null, }`

Comment: @WarrenJennings yes. What you essentially want is:  `(await (await fetch(address)).json())`

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AyushGupta pointed out that I needed to change:

```
var returned = await fetch(address)
```

to:

```
var returned = (await (await fetch(address)).json())
```